# Cloudformation : Encountered unsupported property DeletionPolicy on S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am using below snippet to provision `S3 Bucket` using `Cloudformation`

and I want to `Retain` the S3 bucket and thus using `DeletionPolicy`.

```
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Condition: ShouldCreateS3Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref S3BackupBucketName
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
```

But when i deploy this template i get the error

```
Encountered unsupported property DeletionPolicy
```

I referred to documentation and [`DeletionPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) property exists

How should i resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be at `S3Bucket` level, not `Properties`:

```
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Condition: ShouldCreateS3Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain 
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref S3BackupBucketName
```

Answer (score 3):

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline while authoring templates along with autocompletion and documentation links:

[image: Visual Studio Code extension]

```
[cfn-lint] E3002: Invalid Property Resources/S3Bucket/Properties/DeletionPolicy
```